# Firefox error: DOMException: The operation is insecure

Tags: javascript, firefox, fabricjs, next.js13

I am implementing an image editor with Fabric JS in my Next js app, I have the functionality to add images to the canvas, I can either add them from my computer which works fine, or from the user's gallery these images are stored in S3, and I fetch them in a pop-up, after user select an image from the gallery, it shows in the canvas, but after I click the Save button

```
  const handleDownload = async () => {
    canvas.discardActiveObject().renderAll();
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvasR = canvasRef.current;

      const dataURL = canvasR.toDataURL("image/png");
      const blob = await fetch(dataURL).then((res) => res.blob());
      const file = new File([blob], "canvasImage.png", {
        type: "image/png",
      });

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("bucket", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MEDIA_BUCKET);

      uploadMediaAPI(formData)
        .then((res) => {})
        .catch((err) =>{});
    }
  };
```

after I click Save this function is triggered to save the final image to a different bucket in s3, but when I add an image from the S3 gallery I get this error [image]

This error is only happening in Firefox, I tried Chrome, Edge, Safari, they all work. I`ll also provide the fucntion that handles putting the image from S3 into the canvas.

```
  const handleFiles = function (file, type) {
    const imgSelected = type ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : file.src;
    setSelectedImage(imgSelected);
    if (imgSelected && canvas) {
      fabric.Image.fromURL(imgSelected, (img) => {
        img.set({
          left: 50,
          top: 50,
        });
        img._element.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        canvas.add(img);
        setLayers([...layers, { object: img }]);
      });
    }
    setOpened(false);
  };
```